# How are the value of two objects linked when I link an object to an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a `tes` test service with two objects shown here in my Typescript code:

```
test: ITestView;
tests: ITestView[];
```

This code checks each object in the `tes.tests` array and when an `id` matches it assigns an object in the array to equal another object `tes.test`:

```
tes.tests.forEach((test: ITestRow) => {
    test.current = false;
    if (test.id == id) {
        tes.test = test; // << Linking them somehow here
        test.current = true;
    }
});
```

Later on I do this:

```
tes.test.current = false;
```

This code sets the value of `tes.tests[0].current` to false and `tes.test.current` to false.

When I now do this:

```
tes.test = null;
```

This code sets the value of `tes.test` to null but does not do anything to the `tes.tests[]` array.

Can someone explain why it does not effect the `tes.tests[]` array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
test = foo; // test references existing object foo
tests[0] = test; // test[0] also references existing object foo
test = null; // test doesn't reference anything, but tests[0] still does
```

Depending on what you expect, you could do:

```
tests[0] = null; // tests[0] doesn't reference anything
```

or:

```
tests.splice(0,1); // removed the 1st item from the tests
// not tests array became shorter!
```

Comment: that's a good way of explaining. Using examples is a really good way to explain concepts. I'll remember that for future answers I write up.

Answer (score 0):

I think the quick and simple answer is that

```
tes.test = null;
```

doesn't destroy the object it's pointing to. `tes.test` now points to nothing.

To clarify, `tes.test.current = false`changed both objects was because it referenced the `current` key of the object `tes.test` was pointing to.

```
tes.test = null;
```

The above code doesn't make any changes to tes.tests[] because it simple makes `tes.test` point to nothing instead of changing the object it is pointing to.
I hope I was clear!